# Unnecessarily mark functions as suspending in favor of common abstraction

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-multiplatform, ktor

I'm working on a project with an API running in the JVM and a JS client to access this API from the browser. The data classes of those objects which are converted to/from JSON are in a multiplatform module so that I can reuse the code on both platforms and don't accidentally end up with mismatched attributes. At this point it would be nice to also have the APIs interface in this mutliplatform module which then would be implemented and hosted in the JVM and implemented and presented in the browser. However, all methods of this interface need to be suspending in the browser since requests are (at least with Ktor's client, which I'm using) while they do not need to be suspending in the JVM.

Is there a good reason against having all those methods suspending even though I don't make use of it in the JVM? I know that methods usually should be suspending only if it's actually needed, but then I would be writing all the same interfaces (besides the suspend keyword) twice which seems like a lot of unnecessary boilerplate code to me. The methods which would unnecessarily be marked as suspending are called from suspending contexts (I'm using Ktor in the JVM too) so restricted usage wouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a matter of preference, really. Both using `suspend` and not using it have disadvantges, so you have to choose which weigh less.

From what you write, it seems that the advantages of using `suspend` (write code only once) outweigh the disavantage of polluting the interface with an unnecessary modifier. I am not aware of the possible runtime overheads here. Personally, I would opt to go *with* `suspend`.

Comment: `suspend` functions are quickly needed when the browser is involved...

Answer (score 1):

> The methods which would unnecessarily be marked as suspending are called from suspending contexts (I'm using Ktor in the JVM too) so restricted usage wouldn't be a problem.

This is the key point: the biggest hassle of the unnecessary `suspend` is having to launch a coroutine. If you're already inside a coroutine, the overhead of just one function along the call path being unnecessarily `suspend` is very low: a single extra object allocated per call.

Answer (score 1):

While it's true that with having one interface you avoid boilerplate and you get the hassle of having to launch a coroutine on JVM, I'd consider another perspective:

When designing your abstraction IMO you shouldn't get much into implementation details, instead of thinking how jvm and/or js handles communication with the api I'd go with the question *"Do I want to leave room for the platforms to handle this communication in an async/suspend way?"*. I believe this way you'll arrive to a more scalable solution, but true you'll lose out on some of the micro-optimizations